# ZeroMQ curve-based security in Node js

Tags: node.js, encryption, zeromq, curve

I am trying to connect my web app (Node js) to a zmq backend which is written in python and using zmq curve encryption. But I am unable to find any helpful example or another resource about curve encryption in Node js. I tried this code :

```
      const zmq = require("zeromq");

      async function run(){
          const sock = new zmq.Request;
          sock.curve_publickey =  'wka2b<1234]+x64D%/a?+l0QS*3XRfhn$i!}3lM}'  // Not the original keys. ;-)
          sock.curve_secretkey =  '?frhwU4mFY1g168tXp64(N6sr/nn{=pQdYP**Ej*'
          sock.curve_serverkey =  '4:U}SW6z?:!]uE44]46.TRGV^4z55+(TTX$}C(DC'
          
          sock.connect("tcp://localhost:9090")
          console.log("Connected to Server")
          
          await sock.send(`Request=GenerateModels|UserId=${user}|FileName=${req.params.name}`)
          const [result] = await sock.receive()
          console.log(result.toString('utf8'))
      }
      
      run()
```

But it doesn't connect to the server. I think I am missing the correct syntax for this. Any help or link to the documentation (searched but no luck) to curve security in zmq (Node js) would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Server:**

```
s.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_SERVER, 1);
s.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_SECRETKEY, new Buffer.from("]W{YFJ^->}wG7*m-o/z8L$yWw}<R%c*]EcU.xDQV"));
s.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_PUBLICKEY, new Buffer.from("rHLUXzqQG$ex{KD/7B#GcT%)f}Li&wo^Ctd*+?Ir"));
```

**Client**:

```
ckeys = zmq.zmqCurveKeypair();
c.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_SERVER, 0);
c.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_SECRETKEY, new Buffer.from(ckeys.secret));
c.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_PUBLICKEY, new Buffer.from(ckeys.public));
c.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_CURVE_SERVERKEY, new Buffer.from("rHLUXzqQG$ex{KD/7B#GcT%)f}Li&wo^Ctd*+?Ir"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it with the latest version `6.x.x`.

```js
var zmq = require('zeromq');

const serverKeypair = zmq.curveKeyPair();
const clientKeypair = zmq.curveKeyPair();

// SERVER
(async () => {

    const sock = new zmq.Publisher({
        linger: 0,
        curveServer: true,
        curvePublicKey: serverKeypair.publicKey,
        curveSecretKey: serverKeypair.secretKey,
    });

    await sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000");
    ...

})();

// CLIENT
(async () => {

    const sock = new zmq.Subscriber({
        linger: 0,
        curveServerKey: serverKeypair.publicKey,
        curvePublicKey: clientKeypair.publicKey,
        curveSecretKey: clientKeypair.secretKey,
    });

    sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")
    ...

})();
```